# cython, compile error(calling C function)

Tags: python, cython

I try to call c library such as below example.

```
# demo.pyx
from libc.math cimport sin

cdef double f(double x):
    return sin(x*x)
```

setup.py

```
# setup.py
from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension
from Cython.Build import cythonize

ext_modules=[
    Extension("demo",
              sources=["demo.pyx"],
              libraries=["m"] # Unix-like specific
    )
]

setup(
  name = "Demos",
  ext_modules = cythonize(ext_modules)
)
```

run setup.py as following

```
%run setup.py build_ext --inplace --compiler=msvc
```

However, following error occur:

```
    running build_ext
building 'demo' extension
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\x86_amd64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -IC:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow35\include -IC:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow35\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\ATLMFC\INCLUDE" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.6.1\include\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\\winrt" /Tcdemo.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.5\Release\demo.obj
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\x86_amd64\link.exe /nologo /INCREMENTAL:NO /LTCG /DLL /MANIFEST:EMBED,ID=2 /MANIFESTUAC:NO /LIBPATH:C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow35\libs /LIBPATH:C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow35\PCbuild\amd64 "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\LIB\amd64" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\ATLMFC\LIB\amd64" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\x64" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.6.1\lib\um\x64" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\lib\winv6.3\um\x64" m.lib /EXPORT:PyInit_demo build\temp.win-amd64-3.5\Release\demo.obj /OUT:D:\etc\cython\demo.cp35-win_amd64.pyd /IMPLIB:build\temp.win-amd64-3.5\Release\demo.cp35-win_amd64.lib
An exception has occurred, use %tb to see the full traceback.
SystemExit: error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\BIN\\x86_amd64\\link.exe' failed with exit status 1181
```

environment: window7, python3.5(64 bit), visual studio 2015 community
python path: C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow35

Please help me solve this problem.

Comment: It would help if the complete error output was shown.

Comment: You apparently run from either a Jupyter notebook or an IPython command-line. Can you try in the plain terminal (cmd.exe)?

Comment: I don't work much with windows, but I would say you don't need to add m-library on Windows (only on Linux). Actually it should not work with `-lm` because there is no such lib on windows. But I may be mistaken.

Comment: Pierre- I try in the plain terminal, but there is same error.

Comment: What install of Python do you use? (specify the origin of the Python install, it if is 32bit or 64bit). Also, from the command-line I expect there to be many more lines to the error. Please copy-paste all of it in the original question.

Comment: I very strongly suspect this is to do with the `-lm` as @ead pointed out

Comment: @PierredeBuyl, there is no more error lines.

Comment: Did you run `%tb` to get the traceback?